# PHP Telegram bot answerInlineQuery not working

Tags: php, inline, bots, telegram

I'm adding inline function to my bot. I'm using PHP only. I wrote this and it seems good to me:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");

$update = json_decode($content, true);

$inlineQuery = isset($update["inline_query"]) ? $update["inline_query"] : "";


if ($inlineQuery["query"] !== "" ) {
    $queryId = $inlineQuery["id"];
    $collection = array(
          "type" => "article",
          "id" => $queryId,
          "title" => "prov",
          "input_message_content" =>   array( "message_text" => "ciao") ,
        );

    $parameters =  array(
    "inline_query_id" => $queryId,
    "results" => $collection,
    );

    $parameters["method"] = "answerInlineQuery";

}

echo json_encode($parameters);
```

I get this error:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"}
```

What do I have to put in id? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($queryId);`?

Comment: string(18) "114300560489130387"

Comment: this is the json {"inline_query_id":"114300560489130387","results":{"type":"article","id":"114300560489130387","title":"prov","input_message_content":{"message_text":"ciao"}},"method":"answerInlineQuery"}

Comment: this is the query inline_query_id=114300560489130387&results%5Btype%5D=article&results%5Bid%5D=114300560489130387&results%5Btitle%5D=prov&results%5Binput_message_content%5D%5Bmessage_text%5D=ciao&method=answerInlineQuery

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs because you answer the request longer than 7-8 seconds after user type something to your inline bot. Try to answer less than 3 seconds

Comment: Please expand your answer. How can the OP make sure his answer is send in less then 3 seconds? How should he edit his code. The thing you posted now is not worth an answer, it is a comment at best.